# Bracket problem with odsfile + includegraphicx

Tags: luatex, brackets, includegraphics, odsfile

The cell that is called should just contain the filename of the desired image file.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{odsfile}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{\includespread*[file=test.ods,sheet=test,range=b2:b2]}

\end{document}
```

I won't compile, presumably because of the brackets. How can I fix this?

Comment: odsfile prints a tabular, you can't use it easily to extract one value.

Comment: I think I got around that using the asterisk.

Comment: I don't see a star in the documentation and when I use it I get a lua error.

Comment: My apologies, it seems this calls for the modified `.sty` file that I have. Please save this as `odsfile2.sty` and call it with `\usepackage{odsfile}`.

https://paste.ee/p/IsPX7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rowtemplate` key to execute custom macros on table contents.

From the documentation:

> Enables to convert tabular data to something different than LATEX
> tables. Syntax for rowtemplates is similar to the table templates,
> variables are inserted with -{number}, where number is the position of
> the cell from beginning of the selection.

For your example it could look like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{odsfile}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includespread[file=test.ods,range=b2:b2,rowtemplate={\includegraphics{-{1}}}]
\end{document}
```

The `-{1}` means that you are using the first column from the selected range.

This is the result using `example-image.png`:

[image]